# I spent six months in the UK on a Short Term Student passport stamp. Can I return on a visitor stamp?

Tags: uk, visa-free-entry, passport-stamps, repeat-visits

I just spent six months in the UK as a student on a passport stamp. Since my parents live in the UK (on a Tier 2 Work visa and a Spouse visa), I would like to return to the UK to see them for a couple of weeks. However, I just left the UK in January. It's March now. How soon can I go back? I really miss them. Is it possible to return since I'll be going back on a different kind of passport stamp?
Thanks!

Comment: There is no fixed Immigration rule on repeat visits. The typical guide is to spend at least the same amount of time outside the UK as in it. If you’re a visa-free national, official advice is to bring the same documents you’d need to apply for a visa, to show to officers at the UK border, to demonstrate that you are a genuine visitor with ties to your country of residence who will leave the UK at the end of their stay https://assets.publishing.service.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/549692/Visitor_Supporting_Documents_Guide_-_English_version.pdf

Comment: A further consideration: if by ‘on a passport stamp’ you mean that you entered visa-free, you should be aware that UK Immigration rules (App3, 25) restrict the type and length of studies a visitor may undertake. https://www.gov.uk/guidance/immigration-rules/immigration-rules-appendix-v-visitor-rules

Comment: You could go back tomorrow, if you can convince the UK immigration officer that you are a genuine visitor and not trying to live in the UK.